# Tailwind CSS flex item overflows outside of parent

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a flexbox with 3 children items that looks something like this:

```
<section className="px-5 flex flex-col md:flex-row md:space-x-10 justify-around">
        <div className="flex flex-col py-3 md:flex-grow"><input ... /></>
        <div className="flex flex-col py-3 md:flex-grow"><input ... /></>
        <div className="flex flex-col py-3 md:flex-grow"><input ... /></>
</section>
```

This works fine in full screen, however flex items start to break out of parent after shrinking the window width (near 1000px).

How can I make it so the items stay inside their parent?

[Fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91HMP.png)

[After shrinking window width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdsJQ.png)

[What I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MByY.png)

Comment: Can you share a code example that demonstrates your problem? For example on https://play.tailwindcss.com

This is your provided example with added colors: https://play.tailwindcss.com/O6A75JDYdi

Comment: @ptts [This](https://play.tailwindcss.com/3xc0Y2WwxR) is almost identical to the real code (items break out between 795px and 768px). Sorry, maybe my question should had been "How can items stay inside their grandparent?"

Answer (score 1):

By adding `flex-wrap` class in the parent(section tag in your case) will fix the issue.

Read more about flex-wrap https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-wrap

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does `flex-wrap` help with that problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use flexbox, you can use `flex wrap` property to solve your proble.,

But i try to get the same result with grid

```html
<div class="container py-10">
  <section class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 p-5 border border-gray-400 rounded-lg">
    <div class="w-full h-20 bg-orange-200 border border-orange-400 rounded-md"></div>
    <div class="w-full h-20 bg-orange-200 border border-orange-400 rounded-md"></div>
    <div class="w-full h-20 bg-orange-200 border border-orange-400 rounded-md"></div>
  </section>
</div>
```

This is better i think :)

Comment: How does `flex-wrap` help with that problem? This is what OP would like to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MByY.png which could be described as "reduce the horizontal gaps between the items in order to make them fit into their parent WHILE KEEPING THEM IN THE SAME LINE".